Memory issues Scanning Large Amounts of Files with SonarQube
With a repo containing 6k+ js files that need to be scanned, I am running into memory issues in SonarQube.
Output is:
....
INFO: 142/6456 files analyzed, current file: js/data/171100080201.js
INFO: 142/6456 files analyzed, current file: js/data/171100080201.js
INFO: 142/6456 files analyzed, current file: js/data/171100080201.js
ERROR: The analysis will stop due to the Node.js process running out of memory (heap size limit 8240 MB)
ERROR: You can see how Node.js heap usage evolves during analysis with "sonar.javascript.node.debugMemory=true"
ERROR: Try setting "sonar.javascript.node.maxspace" to a higher value to increase Node.js heap size limit
....

I increased the maxspace, but it just throws the error after twice as many files... so this isn't a solution.
Without getting the repository developer in the mix... e.g. dividing files into folders and using:
sonar.module.module1.name and .sources

How can I get my pipeline to break the total files into manageable batches? This might happen with pipelines in the future, so exploring ideas on how to cover any such issue with many files in the repos.
